Stripe how to capture last4 card digits in checkout.session.completed
I create payment links as below
//Create payment link
    var quantity int64 = 1
    linkParams := &stripe.PaymentLinkParams{
        LineItems: []*stripe.PaymentLinkLineItemParams{
            {
                Price:    &priceObj.ID,
                Quantity: &quantity,
            },
        },
        Params: stripe.Params{
            Metadata: map[string]string{
                "id": 'some id',
                "value": 'some value',
            },
        },
    }
    result, linkError := paymentlink.New(linkParams)

Then when user clicks on this payment link, payment form is opened and my webhook is triggered once payment is processed.
I listen for events 'charge.succeeded' and 'checkout.session.completed'
So here's the issue, I need last4 digits of the card (which I get with 'charge.succeeded' but not with 'checkout.session.completed') and also the metadata I set while creating payment link (which I get with 'checkout.session.completed' but not with 'charge.succeeded')
So is there a way to get both last4 digits and metadata in any 'checkout.session.completed'?
I tried many things like accessing PaymentIntent with id but doesn't get the values.

The best way to capture both last4 and metadata would be to just listen for both events and cache their contents for easy lookup.
If you absolutely must have a serialized workflow for each of those attributes, the best way to get them from a single webhook will depend on which Event you're listening to.
For example:
To get last4 from the checkout.session.completed Event, you would need to get the Charge object that's associated with that Checkout Session's Payment Intent. This would look like so:

Ingest the checkout.session.completed webhook Event
Pull out the ID on the Checkout Session's payment_intent attribute (see here)
Use the Payment Intent ID to retrieve the Payment Intent (see here), making sure to expand the latest_charge object (see here for attribute, see here for using expand)
Parse the payload from the Retrieve API call performed in step 3 and look for latest_charge.payment_method_details.card.last4

A similar method would work for getting metadata from charge.succeeded, except you would use the Charge's payment_intent ID to make a List All Checkout Sessions API call that filters on that specific Payment Intent.

Thanks but I have already tried this
paymentIntent, err := paymentintent.Get(session.PaymentIntent.ID, params)
last4Digits := paymentIntent.LatestCharge.PaymentMethodDetails.Card.Last4
but it's' always empty

Either your Payment Intent hasn't had a successful payment on it yet, or your code is looking in the wrong place. Can you log the value for paymentIntent and step through each nested value to confirm?
